# Keeping a mass on a beam elevated?

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, torque

I've just started learning physics – having just learned Newtons laws – so a real beginner. I thought I had the physical knowledge to solve a particular issue but have not been able to translate my intuition into math.

I'm interested in understanding the variables relevant to keeping a beam containing a mass at one end upright by holding the other end of the beam at some angle $\theta$. In my case, the point of rotation is the exact same point where force is applied.

So to be clear, we have a rigid beam connected on one end to a motor (or another device where point of effort is the same as the point of rotation ) and on the other end of the beam is a mass. I want to keep the beam elevated at a certain angle using force from the motor. How do I do this? What are the relevant physical variables?

Here's what I do know:

1. To keep just the mass up I need a normal force of $mg$ to counteract the force of gravity.
2. Which can be broken down into perpendicular components along a coordinate plane rotated by $\theta$: $mg\sin\theta$ and $mg\cos\theta$.
3. Intuitively the length of the beam seems to be relevant.

My intuition tells me that were the motor to stop applying force the beam would act like a pendulum. My difficulty is:

**Where is force being applied and how do I calculate it**

This raises a larger question, which is how to approach physical problems in newtonian mechanics which I ask but may not be able to answer. Is this all derivable from $F=ma$ and I don't see it or must new equations be developed empirically?

Comment: I think you are asking for someone to teach you, as an alternative to asking your teacher or classmates or studying your textbook.

Comment: I'll give you points for having a model that can accurately describe the data. But you are incorrect in implying it is the only model. (1) You assume I'm using a textbook, (2) that I'm learning this in a class, (3) that my class is learning about torque, (4) that you have access to all the data. Even were all these true, what is the problem with taking advantage of SE? What's wrong with using alternatives? Your question undermines the very purpose of SE. I'm quite disturbed by your comment and hope it will be deleted and the downvote undone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've said you're just beginning you might not have heard of a thing called **Torque**.This is what is used in these situations and in your case it is the Torque from the motor which keeps the beam in whatever desired angle.Of course the torque from the motor is a result of internal forces inside the motor but we really don't bother.So to answer your question of what variables to consider they are the

1)Force applied by the weight = $F$

2)The perpendicular distance of the force from the axis of rotation of the beam = $d$

3)The angle between the direction of force and the beam (more generally the line joining the force applied and the axis of rotation) = $\theta$

Mathematically it is given as $Torque(\tau) = Fdsin(\theta)
$

And of course as you've thought the length of the beam is relevant as it is obvious in the equation above.

Understanding torque would make these problems easier for you i guess.

Answer (score 0):

We define these variables:

m = mass to be applied at the end of the beam
w = weight of the beam
l =length of your beam
a = angle of the beam from horizon measured counter clockwise
T = moment of beam at support which is = (m.l+ w.l/2).cos(a)

Which has to be countered by the torque of your motor.

The required torque can be generated by direct connection to the motor or attached to the motor via a gear-box or set of belts and pulleys.
If your beam is rigid as you defined once it has been elevated into position by the motor it will stay still unless the motor does not have a positive lock.

In that case the system can either wobble or vibrate depending on the rotational stiffness of the gear-box or its clutch.
We will need other properties of the beam such as its material and cross section to determine stresses on the beam at any given point or the details of its connection to the motor shaft.